# can i use where condition while i am doing count(),

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing about `count()` method, but it seems like cannot add where condition in there, so anyone can teach how to do it? I just wanna to show out the id which both are the same, appreciated if you reply m

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  W.title,A.firstname,A.lastname,w.ARTISTID,a.artistid,
    COUNT (*) As NumberOfWork
    FROM dtoohey.ARTIST a ,dtoohey.WORK W
    GROUP BY W.TITLE,A.firstname,A.lastname,w.ARTISTID,a.artistid
    HAVING COUNT(*)>3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `where` clause; I suspect you just put it in the wrong place. It should come before the `group by` clause, [as shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDDCHGF):

[image]

So you can do:

```
SELECT W.title,A.firstname,A.lastname,w.ARTISTID,a.artistid,
    COUNT (*) As NumberOfWork
FROM dtoohey.ARTIST a ,dtoohey.WORK W
WHERE w.artistid = a.artistid
GROUP BY W.TITLE,A.firstname,A.lastname,w.ARTISTID,a.artistid
HAVING COUNT(*)>3;
```

But it would be better to use modern explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT W.title,A.firstname,A.lastname,w.ARTISTID,a.artistid,
    COUNT (*) As NumberOfWork
FROM dtoohey.ARTIST a
JOIN dtoohey.WORK W
ON w.artistid = a.artistid
GROUP BY W.TITLE,A.firstname,A.lastname,w.ARTISTID,a.artistid
HAVING COUNT(*)>3;
```

I've also taken out the `distinct` clause as you don't need that with `group by`.